# SVN: "Inconsistent line ending style" - Checking in a file with ^M intentionally

Tags: svn, bash

Using svn version 1.3.1 (unable to upgrade due to a configuration controlled CM server) on CentOS 4.2.

My code (a bash script) specifically has a ^M in it for an important reason. Unfortunately, subversion will not let me check this file in. It complains that:

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Inconsistent line ending style
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:

I have proven that removing the single ^M from my code allows it to be checked in. How do I tell subversion that the ^M is intentional and that it should allow the file to be checked in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to **remove the svn:eol-style property** from your file. Subversion didn't care about line endings in your file until this property was added. To quote the [subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.eol-style):

> This means that by default, Subversion
>   doesn't pay any attention to the type
>   of end-of-line (EOL) markers used in
>   your files.

The book then goes on describing how you can make subversion care about the line endings by setting the `svn:eol-style`, which is exactly what you *don't* want.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to get rid of the control character in the program in the first place; this might have other compatibility benefits, and might avoid problems with editing in the future.

You can generate a `\r` in bash easily with

```
`printf '%b' '\015'`
```

So, for example:

```
$ echo abc`printf %b '\015'`def
def
$
```

Or:

```
$ c=`printf %b '\015'`
$ set | grep ^c=
c=$'\r'
$
```

(*Note:* I know there are easier ways than by calling printf. Unfortunately, those easier ways are different in bash and posix shells. A bash-only solution is quite nice: `$'\r'`. Ash-only even nicer: `c='\r`. I'm not sure if `ash` does this because it's ash or because it's posix.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's being used as a string or something. Doesn't bash have a way to encode characters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `svn:eol-style` property:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style LF myscript.sh
```

will cause Subversion to always treat the file as having LF-style line-endings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the svn:mime-type property to something none-text based (like application/octet-stream ?). This might make subversion ignore the line endings.

Have a look at the [File Content Type](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type) section of the svnbook.